# How to check if a Regex expression matches an entire string in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regex expressions so sorry if this is a really noob question.

I have a regex expression... What I want to do is check if a string matches the regex expression in its entirety without the regex expression matching any subsets of the string.

For example...

If my regex expression is looking for a match of \s*A*\s*, it should return a match if the string it is comparing it to is "   A       " but if it compares to the string " A B" it should not return a match.

Any help would be appreciated? I code in C#.

Comment: You can try an online regex tester at http://regexpal.com/ most simple C# regex pattern should be ok to be tested correctly.

Comment: Actually, the `\A` (at the start) and `\z` (at the end) must be used to make sure the entire string is matched.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You would normally use the start end end anchors `^` and `$` respecitvely:

```
^\s*A*\s*$
```

Keep in mind that, if you regex engine supports multi-line, this may also capture strings that span multiple lines as long as one of those lines matches the regex(since `^` then anchors after any newline or string-start and `$` before any newline or string end). If you're only running the regex against a single line, that won't be a problem.

If you want to ensure that a multi-line input is only a single line consisting of your pattern, you can use `\A` and `\Z` if supported - these mean start and end of *string* regardless of newlines.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot or don't want to change the regular expression, then you can also use:

```
var match = regex.Match(pattern);
if (match.Success && match.Length == pattern.Length)
{
    // TODO: Entire string was matched, and not a sub string
}
```